# layout turtles using link weight

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to layout my turtles taking into account the link weights, but it looks like no primitives are using link attributes.

In my case links can have weights from -3 to 3, and the ideal visualization will push together (or pull away) turtles with a force proportional to their link weight.

Is there any undocumented or experimental primitive for this?

Comment: why don't you just use whatever layout is closest to what you want, and then simply move turtles toward / away from each other based on the link weight? There is no existing `layout` that does what you want.

Comment: Easy to say but how would you implement such a positioning strategy?

Comment: pick your `layout`, then `ask` each turtle to face the turtle at the `other-end` and move `forward` or `back` in accordance with the link attribute that is your weight.